# How can I associate custom widgets with TreeItems in SWT?

Tags: java, user-interface, widget, swt

I have created a custom widget--an SWT Group that consists of several buttons, labels, images and perhaps several other widgets I might need to add in the future. I would like to make this custom widget a tree item, so that I can get the indentation and the expand/collapse functionality of a tree.

Here is an image that shows what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

I created this example with the Google Web Toolkit and I'd like to implement it with SWT.

The SWT TreeItem has methods to set the text and the image, but I could not find a way to make the tree item be a custom widget. If it is not possible to associate custom widgets with SWT tree items, suggestions about other ways to organize custom widgets in a tree with indentation and expand/collapse functionality would be very helpful too. Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at JFace `TreeViewer` instead.

Comment: @Baz Thank you for the suggestion, Baz. I took a look at the JFace `TreeViewer`, but from what I understood, the support for customized tree items is still quite limited. A `LabelProvider` can be used to set an image and text for each item contained in the tree viewer, but I couldn't find a way to have "fancier" items, like the ones on the picture above. The `TreeViewer` tutorials and code snippets I found all had pretty simple tree items with just an image and a text label...

Comment: `TreeViewer`s are very similar to `TableViewer`s, so you might want to try something like [this](http://www.subshell.com/en/subshell/blog/Eclipse-RCP-Comboboxes-inside-a-JFace-TableViewer100.html) but for a `TreeViewer` instead. I don't have the time right now to test it though...

Comment: You could also look at using `org.eclipse.jface.viewers.OwnerDrawLabelProvider`

Comment: Someone pointed me to the [PGroup widget](http://www.eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/pgroup/pgroup.php) from the Eclipse Nebula project. It is not in the standard release of SWT, but I tried it out and it seems to be almost exactly what I need for the functionality described above.

Comment: On a separate note, what is the best way to indicate that I believe the PGroup is the answer to my original question? Is leaving the previous comment enough or is there a better way to go about this? Sorry, I am still quite new to stackoverflow...

Comment: @Stef You can post an answer to your own question and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [PGroup](http://www.eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/pgroup/pgroup.php) widget from the Eclipse Nebula project does the job. It lets you enclose SWT Composites and supports collapsing and expanding. Indentation can be achieved by using layouts (e.g., GridLayout) for the contents of the PGroup and layout data (e.g., GridData) to specify the indentation of a component inside the PGroup.

The ExpandBar (which is a standard SWT [widget](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/widgets/)) also seems like a possible solution, but I have not experimented with it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be possible to use an event `SWT.PaintItem` to add custom drawing:

https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-CustomDrawingTableAndTreeItems/customDraw.htm

Source: 
[Embed custom widget in SWT Tree or Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37755860/embed-custom-widget-in-swt-tree-or-table)

```
1   Display display = new Display();
2   Shell shell = new Shell(display);
3   shell.setBounds(10, 10, 350, 200);
4   Image xImage = new Image (display, 16, 16);
5   GC gc = new GC(xImage);
6   gc.setForeground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_RED));
7   gc.drawLine(1, 1, 14, 14);
8   gc.drawLine(1, 14, 14, 1);
9   gc.drawOval(2, 2, 11, 11);
10  gc.dispose();
11  final int IMAGE_MARGIN = 2;
12  final Tree tree = new Tree(shell, SWT.CHECK);
13  tree.setBounds(10, 10, 300, 150);
14  TreeItem item = new TreeItem(tree, SWT.NONE);
15  item.setText("root item");
16  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
17     TreeItem newItem = new TreeItem(item, SWT.NONE);
18     newItem.setText("descendent " + i);
19     if (i % 2 == 0) newItem.setData(xImage);
20     item.setExpanded(true);
21     item = newItem;
22  }
23  tree.addListener(SWT.MeasureItem, new Listener() {
24     public void handleEvent(Event event) {
25        TreeItem item = (TreeItem)event.item;
26        Image trailingImage = (Image)item.getData();
27        if (trailingImage != null) {
28           event.width += trailingImage.getBounds().width + IMAGE_MARGIN;
29        }
30     }
31  });
32  tree.addListener(SWT.PaintItem, new Listener() {
33     public void handleEvent(Event event) {
34        TreeItem item = (TreeItem)event.item;
35        Image trailingImage = (Image)item.getData();
36        if (trailingImage != null) {
37           int x = event.x + event.width + IMAGE_MARGIN;
38           int itemHeight = tree.getItemHeight();
39           int imageHeight = trailingImage.getBounds().height;
40           int y = event.y + (itemHeight - imageHeight) / 2;
41           event.gc.drawImage(trailingImage, x, y);
42        }
43     }
44  });
45  shell.open();
46  while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
47     if (!display.readAndDispatch()) display.sleep();
48  }
49  xImage.dispose();
50  display.dispose();
```