# Embed custom widget in SWT Tree or Table

Tags: java, swt

Using SWT, Is it possible to create a custom widget and insert it to a `Table` or `Tree` as if it was a `TreeItem` or `TableItem`?

I tried to create a class and extend `TreeItem` but I'm getting this warning:

```
MyClass illegally extends TreeItem
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: This may be worth reading: [Building and delivering a table editor with SWT/JFace](https://eclipse.org/articles/Article-Table-viewer/table_viewer.html).

Comment: Also this: [Add SWT Widgets to the cells of the Table](http://alexander.lds.lg.ua/2010/11/add-swt-widgets-to-the-cells-of-the-table/).

Answer (score 2):

Most SWT widgets are not designed to be extended and enforce this by checking that the current class is in the `org.eclipse.swt.widgets` package. This can be worked around but is very strongly discouraged.

Widgets generally contain a lot of platform specific code, an override class might very easily end up using code which will only work on one platform.

There are various other ways to extend tables and trees. Using `TableEditor` and `TreeEditor` is one way. Drawing the table/tree yourself using `SWT.MeasureItem`, `SWT.PaintItem` and `SWT.EraseItem` is another.

Comment: I see, I'm going to take a look at `TreeEditor`, what I'm trying to do is to change the color of a range of text of a TreeItem, unfortunately, this is a really old and complex application so it will be really hard to move to TreeViewer, which has an easy way to achieve this

Comment: Coloring the text is best done with the custom draw using `SWT.PaintItem`.. see [Custom Drawing Table and Tree Items](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-CustomDrawingTableAndTreeItems/customDraw.htm)